# Skorohod Space with $J_1$ topology homeomorphic to Frechet Space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, metric-spaces

Is the Skorohod space $D([0,T];\mathbb{R}^d)$ equipped with the $J_1$ topology homoeomorphic to a separable Fr\'{e}chet space.  In particular, is it homeomorphic to $L_{\mu}^1(\mathcal{B}([0,1])$ where $\mu$ is a Borel measure on $[0,1]$?

Comment: For the second part, it is worth noting that all (infinite dimensional) separable Fréchet spaces are homeomorphic.

Comment: True, but is there an explicit such homeomorphism?